# Почему в MVC4 не работет директива @import для импорта css стилей?

Tags: c#, css3, asp.net-mvc, razor

Доброго времени суток!!!

Поясните, пожалуйста, почему такой код не работает в Visual C# MVC приложении:

```
<style>
  @import url(Styles.css);
</style>
```

Компилятор ругается на закрывающий тег **`</style>`**. Работает только если подключать файл стиля через тег **`<link>`** или такая запись:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles.css")
```

Буду очень рада вашим ответам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@import` - это ключевое слово в Razor. Если вам нужен `@import` как строка в выходном html, то вам надо заэсекйпить `@` как `@@`:

```
<style>
  @@import url(Styles.css);
</style>
```

Comment: спасибо!))) Помогло) Правда, всё равно не удалось грамотно разбить один файл стилей на несколько. Пришлось вернуться к громоздкому общему файлу(((